# android application configuration files

Tags: android, file, configuration, storage

An application has a number of configuration files which should be provided by user. These are large xml files which store many parameters and protocol descriptions for the application. User should place it somewhere on a device.

Which strategy is more acceptable?

1. save the files path in the application settings and load these files on the application startup;
2. upload the files to some internal application storage like application assets, sqlite db or settings to use them independently of the original storage place.

What's the best place where user should download files? Are there any dedicated paths for such cases in Android?

Comment: You say "provided by the user" then later, "downloaded".  Which is it?  Please explain the use case more clearly.

Comment: equal meaning...downloaded by USB to some place on a device with using common tools

Comment: Downloaded from inside the app?  Or via browser/download manager?

Comment: not from inside, via browser/download manager

Comment: Then you have a problem since you cannot control where those files end up.  You will need to use a `FileObserver` to receive events for those files being created then move them into internal storage.  Private files are where they want to end up since they are then protected from deletion/modification outside your app.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration files should be stored in the internal app storage since these files are important for app and if they are stored in external storage media or user can able to access they might change the file (ie delete or edit) this will inject more bugs into the app.

Comment: That's reasonable answer but then the application have to be improved with a bunch of burden options like keeping storage up to date if files a changed, look up for files format compatibility between the app versions, show current files for user and etc. In case the files out of the application the user should care about all these difficulties. ;)